# Change chapter numbering in body and ToC

Tags: table-of-contents, tocloft

To change the numbering of chapters I have included this in the preamble:

```
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Alph{chapter}}

\titleclass{\chapter}{straight}
\titleformat{\chapter}[block]%
   {\bfseries\large\sffamily\color{blue}}{SUBPART \thechapter}{10pt}{\hangindent=2.7em\hangafter=1\large}
```

With this in the document the numbering of chapters goes like SUBPART A, SUBPART B....
But in the ToC they go as A, B... without taking the SUBPART into account I guess that I have to include SUBPART in the definition of \thechapter but do not see how

Comment: The simplest, since you use `titlesec` , would be to use `titletoc` for the toc formatting, more precisely \titlecontents{chapter}{...}`.

Comment: Tks Bernard, I have tried with title  contents but \thechapter is not read: \titlecontents{chapter}[0pt]{\normalsize\protect\addvspace{15pt}}%
{\bfseries\small\sffamily{SUBPART \thechapter}}{ }%\chaptername{}
{\enspace\titlerule\contentspage}%

Comment: Could you post a complete, yet minimal, code of what you've tried?

Answer (score -1):

Tks Bernard, I have prepared a MWE, solved the issue with the chapter but cannot solve two things the \appendix declaration in memoir is not doing anything (names of chapters do not change) and dotted lines in ToC are not printed, may be a clash of packages? I have left in the preamble all the packages I am using although they are not needed in this MWE:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,8pt]{memoir}            
%\usepackage[]{appendix}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{atveryend}%%%% <--- ! thumb index
\usepackage[ukrainian,english]{babel}
\usepackage{bbding}
\usepackage{boldline}
%\usepackage{boolexpr}%boolean loops
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
%\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage{framed} 
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage[left=3.0cm,right=3.0cm,top=4.0cm,bottom=3.0cm,headheight=2.8cm,headsep=0.8cm,textwidth=15.0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{keyval}%numberless sections, etc
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{makecell}
%\usepackage{marvosym}%e-mail \Email
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{pageslts}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{pifont}%acft symbol et al
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{textcomp}% textdagger textborn textopenbullet
\usepackage[height={2cm},distance={2cm},width=1.5cm,topthumbmargin={auto},bottomthumbmargin={auto}]{thumbs}%%%% <--- ! thumb index
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,shapes.arrows,calc,positioning,shadows,trees}
\usepackage[newparttoc]{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{url}%long urls
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{wasysym}%other symbols (pointer)
%
\renewcommand*{\cftchapterleader}{
 \normalfont\cftdotfill{\cftsectiondotsep}}
 %
\titleclass{\part}{top}
\titleformat{\part}[block]
  {\bfseries\LARGE\sffamily}{PART~\thepart}{10pt}{\LARGE}
%  
\titleclass{\chapter}{straight} 
\titleformat{\chapter}[runin]% 
{\bfseries\large\sffamily}{SUBPART~\thechapter~ -- ~}{0pt}{\hangindent=3.7em\hangafter=1\large}

\titlecontents{chapter}% <section-type>
  [0pt]% <left>
  {\hangindent7.0em}% <above-code>hangindent segunda línea en títulos largos
  {\bfseries SUBPART\ \thecontentslabel\quad}% <numbered-entry-format>
  {}% <numberless-entry-format>
  {\bfseries\hfill\contentspage}% <filler-page-format>

\titleformat{\section}
  {\bfseries\large\sffamily}{SECTION~\thesection}{0.5em}{}
  %
  \titlecontents{section}% <section-type>
  [.7cm]% <left>
  {}% <above-code>
  {\bfseries SECTION\ \thecontentslabel\quad}% <numbered-entry-format>
  {}% <numberless-entry-format>
  {\bfseries\hfill\contentspage}% <filler-page-format>
%
%
\titlespacing*{\part}{0pt}{10pt}{10pt}  
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{20pt}{10pt}  
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{10pt}{10pt} 
%
\renewcommand{\thepart}{\arabic{part}} 
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Alph{chapter}}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
%
\setlength\cftchapternumwidth{1.5em}
\setlength\cftsectionnumwidth{2.3em}
%
\begin{document}
%
\pagenumbering{arabic} 
\begin{KeepFromToc}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Contents}
\tableofcontents
\end{KeepFromToc}%
\newpage
\chapter{First}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Second}
\lipsum[1]
\appendix
\appendixname
\chapter{First}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please don't use the answer section for a post that isn't an answer to the question (even if you're the one who posted the question). Just edit the question and add the additional information directly there. Thank you.